# Endless scrolling horizontal scrollview with limited visible items

Tags: android, android-layout

I want an simple endless scrolling horizontal scrollview with limited visible items like in following image : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDqkn.jpg

Like in this image 4 views visible at a time, and last item showing on left side of first item, like any carousel works.

Currently I am using simpel HorizontalScrollView :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itv_tabs_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

<!--Some Views-->

       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

but I need that to be circular.. like I can move that to both direction without any limitation

Any suggestion or links will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: it looks like you need horizontal `RecyclerView` with infinite (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) count of items, starting at middle position (`Integer.MAX_VALUE/2`), and `getItem` returning `items.get(position%items.size())`. Show your current work, adapter and list initiation

Comment: Currently I have added a simple Horizntal scrollView, but I need that to be circular.. like I can move that to both direction without any limitation.

Comment: I used android.widget.HorizontalScrollView

Comment: try PagerTitleStrip it may help.

Comment: `HorizontalScrollView` is wrong way, you need recycling for endless smooth scrolling

Comment: pls suggest any link.. I never worked with this type of view.. so no idea about this, pls guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) with following changes:

1. In RecyclerView element in xml add `android:orientation` property with value `horizontal`

   ```
   <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal" /> // <-- this is changed
   ```
2. After setting up `RecyclerView` scroll to middle position:

   ```
    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
   ```
3. Update `onBindViewHolder()` to return correct `ViewHolder` in case value exceeds limit:

   ```
   // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       // - get element from your dataset at this position
       // - replace the contents of the view with that element
       holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position % mDataset.length]);  // <-- this is changed
   }
   ```
4. Finally, return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` from `getItemCount()`

   ```
   // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   }
   ```

**Limitation:**
I am assuming that the user won't scroll the view `Integer.MAX_VALUE`/2 times otherwise they would reach the end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: isn't there any other way than recycler view? because I have already implemented all clicks by managing that in CustomTabs layout.. I just want to make it left side scrollable.

Comment: I fixed this by using whole CustomTabManager in recyclerView.